# When installing Windows service and then trying to run, I get an Error 1053. Saying my service is taking too long to start

Tags: c#, windows-services

> Error 1053: windows service not start timely fashion

I have set up my service exactly how it was shown in countless online tutorials, but my OnStart method still doesn't seem to be getting called at all. This process is supposed to run and then loop infinitely and constantly check a server for commands to run. Here's my Main:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
        {
            new AgentService(args)
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
}
```

Here's what my service constructor and `OnStart` look like:

```
public AgentService(string[] args)
{
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Args = new ServiceArguments();
        this.ValidArgs = this.Args.SetArgs(args);
        this.AgentCycle = Int32.Parse(Args.Cycle);
}

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
        ServiceStatus serviceStatus = new ServiceStatus
        {
            dwCurrentState = ServiceState.SERVICE_START_PENDING,
            dwWaitHint = 100
        };
        this.CimCommands = new Dictionary<string, CimCommand>();
        SetServiceStatus(this.ServiceHandle, ref serviceStatus);
        serviceStatus.dwCurrentState = ServiceState.SERVICE_RUNNING;
        SetServiceStatus(this.ServiceHandle, ref serviceStatus);

        if (this.ValidArgs) 
           RunAgent();
}
```

I am handing in args via the command line, but if none are given, I am using environment variables. All are present on my machine so I can't understand why my service is not starting in a "timely manner". I only have 2 extra dependencies. One is `Newtonsoft.Json`, the other is `RestSharp`.

I've also tried writing it as a console app using TopShelf, but I had the same error that way. The logic is all sound, I've already tested my methods. Any ideas?

**EDIT**: okay, here's the best way to explain the goal of this service... The service is supposed to call an api/server every 5 seconds and then receive a json that tells it what command to run on the windows machine. once it finishes all those commands, it asks the server again if there is any work to complete and it starts all over. The custom types are simply json_objects to use with Newtonsoft and the Service Arguments is just an object with 5 string values, and 1 bool. And then functions for parsing the arguments from either the cmd line, environment variables, or a config file.

Comment: Actually it is telling you that your `OnStart` takes to long to finish. Propably has something to do with you setting a Wait Time to 10000? | Also, how would you *know* if the service is called or not? It is not like you can display a UI from a Service.

Comment: Good point. I guess I don't technically know that, but as far as the wait time thing, I was getting this error before that was in there. I added it to try to solve this issue, but it didn't help so maybe I should've removed it to avoid confusion.

Comment: You use a whole host of types and variables you gave us no information about. And some of your variables have the same Name as a type too, just to maximize confusion? | Let us start with what this code is supposed to be doing. What is the goal of this Service?

Comment: @Christopher Okay, I've updated the description with that bit at the bottom. Does that help?

Comment: With the stated Design, I would go for a Queue as the collection. | As services are so damn hard to debug - lacking a UI, needing to be installed, attaching the Debugger - a lot of people have take to replicate the Service Managers basic flow in a console application. | As RunAgent() is not a pre-existing function, what are you doing in there? Starting any possibly infinite loops?

Comment: Yes, there is most definitely an infinite loop in the function being called from RunAgent. @Christopher

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, there is most definitely an infinite loop in the function being called from RunAgent.

While `RunAgent()` does not return, `OnStart()` does not. When `OnStart()` does not return, the Service Manager will just kill the process because "it takes to long to start". Do not put infinite loops into the OnStart Function!

For once the message is exactly what it says. It also does exactly waht it is there for (getting you to fix your faulty code). For polling you need something like a Timer that you start in "onStart()". Maybe a seperate Background Task or Thread. Not a custom loop you block OnStart() with.

Comment: Thank you so much. You're amazing. I knew it was something silly, but I didn't expect that to be the issue. Really appreciate the help!